# Process reuse - async BeginOutputReadLine problem

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process, reusability

I've encountered an interesting problem.

C# allows reusing process resource (according to MSDN) - so I call instance Start() method after process is finished:

```
Process p = new Process();
// init
p.Start();
```

And some time later:

```
p.Kill();
// not important
p.Start();
```

When I have a thread performing sync read everything seems to be ok - output is being read after first and second Start() call.

Now the funny thing. When I use async read (everything initialized properly):

```
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

output is being read only after first Start() call. After second call process is started without any output being redirected.

I've also tried calling Cancel and Begin once more:

```
p.CancelOutputRead();
p.Kill();
// not important
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

with same result.

Some machine details: Win 7 Ultimate x86 SP1 (CPU also x86), tested on .NET 2.0 / 3.0, VS 2008

The question is - is it some framework bug or my misunderstanding of the Process.Start definition ("Starts (or reuses) the process resource that is specified by the StartInfo property of this Process component and associates it with the component.")? Any help much appreciated.

I suppose the solution is recreation of the process object, but it'll probably be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Kill` makes it necessary to add your event handler for [`OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) again before calling `Start`.

Comment: Nope, I reset StartInfo and Process fields and it still doesn't work. I've written a small app (about 50lines of code) for tests without any external executable or code.